# Using localtime function to get error in rails

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, localtime

I am developing `Rails 4 application` where i have to get `signin` value and display it as a `localtime`. But i got issue when i fetch signin value from database and use localtime to convert it into `local datetime.`

```
userdatetime = users.signin.localtime

undefined method `localtime' for "2015-09-15T00:00:00.000Z":String
```

If any one have a solution then please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`signin` return a `String` object, a string doesn't have `localtime` method. Try

```
 Time.parse(users.signin).localtime
```

Comment: Got this error : no implicit conversion of time into string

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `localtime' for "2015-09-15T00:00:00.000Z":String

Change this

```
userdatetime = users.signin.localtime
```

to

```
userdatetime = users.signin.to_time.localtime
```

Comment: Got this error : no implicit conversion of time into string

Comment: How did you know his implementation of the user model?

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing with DateTime:

```
user_datetime = DateTime.parse(users.signin).to_time.localtime
```

Comment: Got this error : no implicit conversion of time into string

Comment: @user1780370 The error you claim doesn't quite make sense to me, cause there's no conversion of time to string in that code. Did you declare userdatetime before? please paste a lager portion of your code

Comment: I got this data from api into users

Comment: I got perfect value when use console

Comment: Even i print Time.at(1259222400) then also get same error of string.. why? I am confused

Comment: Why don't you break it down and print to logs to see what happened?